# Validating date between opening hours in JS

Tags: javascript, validation, date, datetime

I was wondering what the best approach would be to validate a date is within the correct opening hours of a shop...

I am creating a website for a golf professional and am taking bookings for lessons on it. I have used fullCalendar for the calendar and integrated it with google calendar so it can be easily sync'd to the pro's mobile easily etc.

As part of the calendar, when a customer clicks on a time slot I am provided with a date object by fullcalendar. I want to validate that this selected slot falls within the opening times of the shop for lessons to be taken etc.

The times will be retrieved from a db table at some point but I can have them returned in JSON onto the page if it works best - but thats not the purpose of this question...

The opening hours differ depending on the day of the week as well as the "season" [summer times -vs- winter times]

```
ie:
 Summer Times
    Monday = 10:00 - 21:00
    Tuesday = 10:00 - 21:00
    Wednesday = 10:00 - 21:00
    Thursday = 10:00 - 21:00
    Friday = 10:00 - 21:00
    Saturday = 08:00 - 18:00
    Sunday = 08:00 - 18:00

 Winter Times
    Monday = CLOSED
    Tuesday = 10:00 - 18:30
    Wednesday = 10:00 - 18:30
    Thursday = 12.00 – 20.30
    Friday = 12.00 – 20.30
    Saturday = 08:00 - 18:00
    Sunday = 08:00 - 18:00
```

What would the "best" way be to validate this?

would the best option be to simply do nested if/switch statements..

```
[sudo code]
if(summer}
{
    switch(date.getDay())
    {
    case 1:
          if(time > mondayOpeningTime && time < mondayCloseTime)
          {
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }
      break;
    case 2:
      execute code block 2
      break;
    .....
    default:
      code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
}
else
{
    // Same as summer logic but for winter times etc..
}
```

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Apologies for the long post/question but thanks in advance to anyone who spends the time reading and responding to it :)

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 arrays: openingTimes and closingTimes. First dimension will be season, second dimension will be day of the week. Then it's just:

```
return ((time > openingTimes[season, dayOfWeek]) && (time < closingTimes[season, dayOfWeek]));
```

Comment: No reason, I just wanted to give others a chance to provide other opinions/options. Marking it now... thanks very much for your responses :)

Comment: Hello from 2015. This answer does not work if you have closing times past midnight (restaurants, night clubs etc).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I wrote up. Quite rough, but takes in to account the case when closing time is after midnight.

Also available at Gist: https://gist.github.com/vtntimo/b5c724371bfb27bfb080

If you create improvements, please contact me :)

```
/*
    Operating hours check
    =====================================

    - Checks if something is open right now
    - Supports closing times going over midnight
    - Feel free to use in whatever you need :)
    - If you make improvements, please inform me!

    Example:

    // Setting operating hours
    // Key 0 is sunday, 1 is monday and so on
    var hours = [
        // Sunday
        {
            open: '08:00',
            close: '16:00'
        },

        // Monday
        {
            allday: true // Open all day
        },

        // Tuesday
        false, // Closed all day

        // Wednesday
        {
            open: '08:00',
            close: '16:00'
        },

        // Thursday
        {
            open: '08:00',
            close: '16:00'
        },

        // Friday
        {
            open: '08:00',
            close: '16:00'
        },

        // Saturday
        {
            open: '08:00',
            close: '16:00'
        },
    ];

    if(isOpen(hours)) {
        alert("We're open!");
    }
    else {
        alert("We're closed!");
    }
*/
function isOpen(hours) {
    var now = new Date();
    var today = now.getDay();

    var yesterday = today - 1;
    if(yesterday < 0) yesterday = 6;

    // Check today's opening hours
    if(hours[today]) {

        // It's open all day today
        if(hours[today].allday) {
            return true;
        }

        // Not open all day
        else {
            var open = hours[today].open;
            var close = hours[today].close;

            // Check if the location is open
            if(checkOpenHours(now,now,open,close)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    // Check yesterday's opening hours in case of closing after midnight
    if(hours[yesterday]) {

        // Not open all day (possibly closing after midnight)
        if(!hours[yesterday].allday) {
            var open = hours[today].open;
            var close = hours[today].close;

            var yesterday_date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), (now.getDate()-1), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            if(checkOpenHours(now,yesterday_date,open,close)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    // Not open
    return false;
}

/*
    Check if "now" is within operating hours
*/
function checkOpenHours(now, operatingDate, open, close) {
    // Splitting times to array
    var o = open.split(":");
    var c = close.split(":");

    // Hours not in proper format
    if(o.length < 2 || c.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    // Converting array values to int
    for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        o[i] = parseInt(o[i]);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i] = parseInt(c[i]);
    }

    // Set opening Date()
    var od = new Date(operatingDate.getFullYear(), operatingDate.getMonth(), operatingDate.getDate(), o[0], o[1], 0, 0);

    // Set closing Date()
    var closingDay = operatingDate.getDate();

    // Closing after midnight, shift day to tomorrow
    if(o[0] > c[0]) {
        closingDay++;
    }
    var cd = new Date(operatingDate.getFullYear(), operatingDate.getMonth(), closingDay, c[0], c[1], 0, 0);

    // Is within operating hours?
    if(now > od && now < cd) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```